# Maven dependency:copy-dependencies -- Get javadoc and sources

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

The Maven goal `dependency:copy-dependencies` copies artifacts together with their poms (if the parameter is set). Is it somehow possible to also grab sources and javadoc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to copy the dependencies, along with their sources and their javadoc in a single pass, but you can use [`classifier`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#classifier) parameter and multiple invocation of the Dependency Plugin:

> Specify classifier to look for. Example: sources

For example, if you want to copy all the dependencies with their sources and javadoc, you could have:

```
mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -Dclassifier=sources
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

Running the 3 commands above on a sample Maven project will copy its dependencies, their sources and javadoc inside the default [output directory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#outputDirectory) which is `target/dependency`. Notice that it doesn't `clean`, in order not to delete the previously copied files.

This could also be done inside of the POM, with 3 execution blocks.

Answer (score 0):

We can use below maven command:

mvn install dependency:sources -Dclassifier=javadoc